# Ignoring folds during F1 macro score computation

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I've been recently working with multiclass classification. The metric I am using is micro F1, called as:

```
f1_score(predictions,real_labels,average="micro")
```

For some folds (I am doing 10f stratified cross validation), I get the:

```
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py:1145: 
UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no true samples.
```

error. I was wondering how I can ignore such folds?

Thank you!

Comment: How big is your samples size and how many classes do you have ?

Comment: I have 7 classes and 133 instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mentioned that you have 133 instances with 7 classes and you are making a 10 stratified fold, so for each fold you will have approximately 13 instances, if one of your classes represents less than 7.5% of the data, you are likely to have a fold with 0 instances of that class, hence the error.

Check your class ratios and either increase the training data or lower the folds number to avoid this warning.

Stratified folding ensures that the class distribution in each fold is similar to the class distribution in the full set, thus if you have a class that represents only 7% of the instances, and while each fold is only 13 instance, then 13*7/100 < 1, which means that there isn't enough data of this class to be represented in each fold of the 10 stratified folds.